# 3 files found with path 'license.html'

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

i'm having problem adding docx4j library to my project, when i sync now and launch the project i got the following error:`3 files found with path 'license.html'. Adding a packagingOptions block may help, please refer to https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.4/com/android/build/api/dsl/ResourcesPackagingOptions for more information` My gradle added `packagingOptions` and `exclude 'META-INF/license.html'`. This error still exists. I have consulted many questions but still do not have an answer. Here is my gradle:`android {
namespace 'com.falcon.printerapp'
compileSdk 34

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdk 26
    targetSdk 34
    versionCode 5
    versionName "2.5"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
    }
}

dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}

buildFeatures {
    viewBinding = true
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        assets {
            srcDirs 'src\\main\\assets'
        }
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.html'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile).configureEach {
    options.fork = true
    options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation"
    options.forkOptions.jvmArgs += [
            '--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED',
            '--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED',
            '--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED',
            '--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED',
            '--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED',
            '--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED',
            '--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED',
            '--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED',
            '--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED',
            '--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm=ALL-UNNAMED',

    ]
}
```

}and implementation:
`implementation("org.docx4j:docx4j-JAXB-Internal:8.0.0") implementation("org.docx4j:docx4j-JAXB-ReferenceImpl:8.0.0") implementation("org.docx4j:docx4j-JAXB-MOXy:8.0.0") implementation("org.docx4j:docx4j-export-fo:8.0.0")`